# Fastest way to replace all elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find the fastest way to replace elements from a numpy array with elements from another one using a mapping rule. I will give you an example because I think it will be most clearly in this way.

Let's say we have these 3 arrays:

```
data = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [1,2,3], [7,5,6]])
map = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
trans = np.array([[10,10,10], [20,20,20]])
```

The `map` array specifies the desired correspondence between `data` and `trans`.

The result I want to get is:

```
array([[11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16], [27, 28, 29], [11, 12, 13], [27, 25, 26]])
```

Each element in the array written above is the sum between the element in `data` and the corresponding element in `trans`.

I am trying to avoid `for loops`, because in reality my `data` and `trans` arrays are way larger, but couldn't figure out the appropriate vectorised function.

Would you please give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index into `trans` with the indices from `map` to select rows off `trans` based on the indices, that act as the row indices for selection and then simply add with `data` -

```
data+trans[map]
```

To do in-situ edit -

```
data += trans[map]
```

Word of caution : I would use another variable name than `map` for the mapping array, which is also a [`Python built-in`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to avoid any undesired behavior.

Sample run -

```
In [23]: data = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [1,2,3], [7,5,6]])
    ...: map1 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
    ...: trans = np.array([[10,10,10], [20,20,20]])
    ...: 

In [24]: trans[map1]
Out[24]: 
array([[10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10],
       [20, 20, 20],
       [10, 10, 10],
       [20, 20, 20]])

In [25]: data + trans[map1]
Out[25]: 
array([[11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 16],
       [27, 28, 29],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [27, 25, 26]])
```

Comment: Oh, I feel so dumb right now. I was trying all these methods but didn't come to my mind this simple and elegant one. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AndreeaD. That happens I guess if one is new to high level language, as the concept of indexing and spawning values takes a bit to grasp.